# PowerBI online gateway to sql server hosted at AWS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have created a power BI dashboard with data from a SQL surver hosted at aws, using power BI desktop.
I have uploaded to power BI online in order to share the dashboard and I have created a cloud gateway for the SQL server but I still can't access the data from Power BI online.
Anyonw knows a solution?

The gateway is online [image]
I am getting the following error:

> ID da atividade: 713cc0ea-b362-4aae-ae4f-5903869c358e
> Solicitar ID: 92f21877-8f28-b15e-0721-1eec92176fec
> ID de correlação: 4d0a8cf2-5da6-7994-1398-792d5e0e72cd
> Hora: Sun Jun 04 2023 18:12:45 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)
> Versão do serviço: 13.0.20819.75
> Versão do Cliente: 2305.5.14128-train
> Cluster URI: https://wabi-south-central-us-redirect.analysis.windows.net/